# How do I dynamically create a wizard control in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a web form that gathers customer information and inserts it into a database.  Customers can have 3 kinds of accounts:  Combined accounts (bill and ship to this location), Billing Accounts (only bill to this location), and shipping accounts (only ship to this location.

The information gathered is broken down into 5 categorizes:  General (store name, address, ext..) employees, owners (of that particular location), trade references, and banking.

I currently have a wizard with 5 steps (one for each category), but I won't need all of them depending on the account type.  Shipping addresses, for instance, requires General and employee information, optionally needs owner information, and should never have Trade Reference nor Banking information.  Also, the user will need to completely fill out the general information category before the account type can be determined.

There doesn't seem to be a way to disable an entire wizard step (by which I mean a link to it doesn't show up on the sidebar and it is impossible to navigate to), so I'd like to dynamically create the wizard so that I only get the steps I need.  The problem is that the wizard is currently 700+ lines of code on the .aspx page, and dynamically creating it will probably take double that (if I'm lucky).

Is there some way I can Statically create each step, then dynamically decide which steps to use in my wizard or is purely dynamic my only option?

Or (and this is the most likely case) is there a much simpler solution that will get me the results I'm looking for?

Comment: Michael, is this a 'canned' wizard? or did you write it yourself? If canned, there should be ways to mark steps as optional based upon data.

Comment: @MarcLyon it's a standard asp wizard.  I can skip over steps using a bunch of nested if statements in the ActiveStepChange event, but as far as I can tell, there is no way to selectively display side bar links; it's all of them or none of them.

Comment: As Dillie-O states below, wizards are an old technique and that server control has not had much love. If you can skip steps in the wizard, can you set the ActiveStep in those nested if statements? I know, it's not the preferable location for business logic like that, but if you're stuck with the wizard, you may have to do something unconventional. So if the user clicks the sidebar item, just skip to the proper step.

Answer (score 0):

Given the highly customizable needs of wizards, a lot of them have gone by the wayside in favor of creating all of the code by hand. It is safe to assume that the wizard you're talking about here is the ASP.Net WebForm Wizard object? I believe that server control has not been updated in a while.

One thing you could look into doing is building all of the UI elements client side, and then have AJAX / WebAPI endpoints do the data processing. By taking this route, you can easily show/hide/customize the various tabs/steps based on the type of account type being processed (you can get that from the URL, or hidden form field, or something else). You can do a google search for "jQuery wizard builder" or something similar to find libraries out there.

Decoupling the presentation from the data processing in this regard will give you more flexibility. It still may take a little more than the 700 lines of code, but you will have greater control over what, how, and when the the data is processed for your end user. You can setup the wizard to post to your service after each step, or wait until all data has been collected before making the submission.